# Invalid response to AJAX call

Tags: ajax, visual-studio, dojo

I'm working on an ASPX web site, and am getting an invalid response from an AJAX xhrPost call back into my code.

I get back a 1x1 pixel white GIF file - which is not supplied by my code.

This even happens when the network cable is unplugged, so my suspicion is that DOJO is doing it itself....

My method in code doesn't even appear to be called - the breakpoints there don't fire.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Please post you JS code. Thanks!

Comment: I think probleme comes from your IIS server !

Comment: I think you may be right ;-(
Whenever I navigate to my code (directly, bypassing the DOJO framework) I still get that one-pixel GIF file - along with a massive style-sheet...
No idea where it's coming from - I've run a full AV, SpyBot_S+D and MalwareBytes scan, and found nothing...

Comment: Note: This only happens for HTTP POST actions, not GET...